# Find columns that contains substring and replace it - Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with special characters in dataframe. For example

```
ID  license     value1     value2   value3 ...
2     a       "5,120.000"    15%     45    ...
1     b       "3,246.440"    10%     65    ...
4     b       "1,890.220"    50%     10    ...
5     c       "2,005.240"    32%     12    ...
```

The problem is that I have so many columns, about 150 and it's not ok if I go column by column and separately replace values. 
So, I need to replace any special characters and transform numbers (at this moment - string columns) to float.

I have tried with something like this:

```
def drop_percent(data):
    for el in data.columns:
        if data[el].astype(str).str.contains('%').any():
            data[el] = data[el].str.strip("%").astype(float)
    return data


def drop_commas(data):
    for el in data.columns:
        if data[el].astype(str).str.contains(',').any():
            mcd[el] = mcd[el].str.replace(',','')
        if data[el].astype(str).str.contains('"').any():
            mcd[el] = mcd[el].str.replace('"', '')
            mcd[el] = mcd[el].astype(float)

    return data
```

The error I have is:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Comment: Try substituting `data[el] = data[el].str.strip("%").astype(float)` for `data[el] = data[el].apply(lambda str: float(str.strip("%")) if isisinstance(str, string) else str)`. Apply the same logic in the other lines

Answer (score 2):

Here's simple and straight forward way of removing all non-special characters from the columns by using a list comprehension and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
(pd.concat([df[col].astype(str).str.replace(r'\W+', '', regex=True) 
           for col in df.columns], 1))

  license   value1 value2 value3
2       a  5120000     15     45
1       b  3246440     10     65
4       b  1890220     50     10
5       c  2005240     32     12
```